# Pandas Python iteration or mod

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do an iteration with Pandas or any built-in function to display multiple of 10 rows for example.

So e.g. there are 50 records and I want to display the **multiple of 10** records which will be record ID 0,10,20,30,40,50.

Comment: Do you want to extract every tenth row? And what do you want to do with them once you extract them?

Comment: You might be able to use `iloc` for this.

Comment: Just for sampling records and yeah i want to extract every 10th records so total records are 50 and every tenth would be 5 or 6 including 0

Comment: Using iloc isnt for when I already know which row it is? I meant like a scenario where there are huge number of records so I can iterate

Comment: Closed found solution

Answer (score 1):

Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[::10, :]
```

This method takes a row/column slice, both based on integer position. More details from documenation:

> Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position.
>   
>   `.iloc[]` is primarily integer position based (from 0 to length-1 of the axis), but may also be used with a boolean array.